# Must a Foriegn Key Be Filled in a Row in a Related Table in a DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, foreign-keys

Consider the following related tables:

[image]

Some `exercises` 'require' a machine, some don't. My thought is to have the `machine` field be a boolean.

Then when saving a `session_set`, if the boolean is `true`, I want to require a `machine_id` foreign key be saved.  If false, the foregin key isn't required.

Is this even possible, or does it refute the total purpose of having a foreign key?

Comment: A NOT NULL SQL FK is a column list whose subrows appear elsewhere as PK or UNIQUE. (Roughly, a relational foreign superkey.) You aren't describing either a NOT NULL or nullable SQL FK, because those things don't act the way you describe. So you shouldn't use "FK" to label your proposal. It is just *reminiscent* of a FK. A (boolean, key) pair in your design corresponds to a (key or NULL) nullable FK value in SQL, where your integrity test "B OR K is in referenced table" corresponds to  SQL's "K IS NULL OR K is in referenced table" integrity test. PS Read a reference and/or manual before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foreign key can be either required or optional (it can or cannot contain null) so you don't need any additional boolean field.

in rails 5 a `belongs_to` association is required by default, so we specify it's `optional`

```
belongs_to :machine, optional: true
```

before rails 5 should be enough

```
belongs_to :machine
```

Now you need to be sure that your field in the database table has no `null: false` constraint and you're set.

I noticed now that your field is called `machine`, not `machine_id` as rails wants by default. In that case try

```
belongs_to :machine, optional: true, foreign_key: :machine
```

Comment: Thanks!  I do have the standard `belongs_to :machine`, and I will add you addendums and test.  Thanks!

Comment: worked like a charm - though I left off the extra foreign key designation, as it already exists in my mirgration